# Installing gem json 2.2.0 failed - windows

Tags: json, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

I got an error trying to install gem json 2.2.0 to my project, so I look for many sites and tutorials but nothing help me with windows.

Please see the problem below:

```
Fetching json 2.2.0
Installing json 2.2.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-2.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0 -r
./siteconf20190412-3460-119pn5l.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-2.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory:
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-2.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/json-2.2.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/json-2.2.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (2.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '2.2.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  calabash-android was resolved to 0.9.8, which depends on
    luffa was resolved to 2.1.0, which depends on
      json
```

For ubuntu the solution was: install libgmp3-dev.
For macOS the solution was: use XCode

But I found nothing for windows. Should be a solution to use RVM? If yes, how can I install it on Windows?

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: When I have errors like this I try to just install the failing gem first, so: `gem install json` and see what you get. You can sometimes get more informative errors that way.

Comment: Also it looks like you are using ruby 2.4 but could you confirm your ruby version and your windows version? If you are using Win 10 do you have the linux subsystem installed?

Comment: Hey @Beartech, sorry for the delay. I have tried many ruby versions, between them: 2.5.1 and 2.6.3 for example. I am using W10 and I do not have linux subsystem installed. What do you think I should do?

Comment: @ItaloPinheiro  Did you find a fix for this?  I have the same problem and have been unable to find a solution.